# What is |= doing in the define function in Java?

Tags: java

Can somebody help me understand what exactly the following function is doing?

```
 int calc(BitSet des) {
        int num =3, numBits = 20;
        int sig = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) { // for each min to find
          sig <<= bph; // shuffle over existing bits
          for(int j = 0; j < numBits; j++) {
            if(des.get(indices[i][j])) {
              sig |= j;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return sig;
      }
```

Comment: `sig |= j; <=> sig = sig | j;` and `|` is the bitwise OR operator.

Answer (score 3):

`sig |= j;` is the same thing as `sig = sig | j`.

This is similar to more familiar operators like `+=` except using the `|` (bitwise OR) operator instead.